# Check condition across several rows from a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some entities A which can all have one or more B. How can I query "all entities A which have this **and** that from B"?

I can query "all entities A which have "this" **or** "that" from B":

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.id
WHERE f = "this" OR f = "that"
GROUP BY A.ID
```

But I can’t check that they have "this" **and** "that", because I can’t check something across different rows from A.

I might use a `GROUP_CONCAT`, but then how can I effectively check that `"blah,thing,foo,bar"` has `blah` and `foo` without some unmaintainable `REGEXP` mess?

(I actually love regexes, but not so much in the context of an SQL query, for something that seems like it wouldn’t need a regex).

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(f)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID
WHERE f = "this" OR f = "that"
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.f) = 2` to your queries.

Comment: On a side note: Double quotes are for names in SQL. Use single quotes for string literals. And you must not `select *` when you aggregate. In your example there are two tables involved, a and b. Your `GROUP BY` clause gets you the a row, but possibly multiple b rows per a row (all rows with 'this' or 'that'). Your `select *` tells the DBMS to show the complete row with all a and b columns. But the b values of which b row? You don't tell the DBMS, which renders your query invalid.

Comment: @Akina It wouldn’t work since I need to check the value of a field `f` from B, not just the count of Bs for a given A.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Maybe in ANSI SQL double quotes wouldn’t work for strings, but I’m using MySQL where you can quote strings with single or double quotes, and use backticks to quote names.
As for using `select *` with `group by`, in my experience it works just fine. The `group by` makes the DBMS choose any one of the B rows associated with the A row (except if you use an aggregate function like `group_concat`, then you will get all the values from B in that column). Using `select B.*` wouldn’t allow be to choose between rows from B, it would just display _only_ the _columns_ from B.

Comment: I know that MySQL allows double quotes for strings if not in ANSI_QUOTES mode. It is better though to have your queries independent from session settings, so better use single quotes. Make also sure to always work in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode (should be the default in most recent versions) in order not to select arbitrary values, because of an invalid query that MySQL doesn't detect as such.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Or maybe I’m too used to working with a DB with all recommended modes turned off? ^^
@Akina Oh sorry I understand what you mean now, since I have a condition `f = 'this' or f = 'that'`, I’ll only get the values I want, in without duplicates thanks to `distinct`. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advice! I’m working on a legacy codebase that has a ton of this kind of thing. It’s a good idea to start writing this kind of queries right, and understand what was wrong with them, before I can someday work my way through cleaning the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I query "all entities A which have this and that from B"?

For such tasks we usually don't join, but use `EXISTS` or `IN` instead. E.g.

```
select *
from a
where id in (select a_id from b where f = 'this')
  and id in (select a_id from b where f = 'that');
```

Here is a solution with an aggregation. In this particular case I see no advantage in using this. There are other situations, though, when an aggregation may be the appropriate solution.

```
select *
from a
where id in 
(
  select a_id 
  from b 
  group by a_id
  having max(f = 'this') = 1
     and max(f = 'that') = 1
);
```

In MySQL true is 1 and false is 0, so taking the maximum of a boolean expression tells us, whether there is at least one row for which the condition is true.

Your own query works, too, by the way, if you add the appropriate `HAVING` clause. And there is no regular expression matching needed for that. As your `WHERE`clause limits f to 'this' and 'that', your `GROUP_CONCAT` result can never be 'this,something_else;that', but only contain 'this' and 'that'. Well, depending on the table there may be duplicates, like 'this,this,that'. Use an `ORDER BY` clause and `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.f IN ('this', 'that')
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.f ORDER BY b.f) = 'that,this';
```

Comment: Awesome! Three solutions for the price of one, thank you so much. I’ll try this and see which one is the better in my case.

Comment: Akina's `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.f) = 2` will work just as fine by the way.

Comment: In the end I first used the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.f)` approach, and then switched to the `id IN (SELECT…)` approach when I needed to check for a more complex condition (has "a" AND ("b" OR "c")). I was afraid this would be slower, but I guess I’m just completely misunderstanding SQL performance, since it seems totally fast enough! :)